# Como acceder a una base de datos que esta en aws desde express

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, mariadb, aws

soy nuevo en backend con nodejs y express, estoy realizando un API REST con express como servidor y lenguaje typescript, el asunto es que quiero conectar mi servidor a una base de datos, mysql/mariadb, que se encuentra en una instancia de aws, he hecho esto:

```
import { createPool } from 'mysql2';
  export async function conectar() {
      const conectando = await createPool({
          host:'myIPInstance',
          port: 3306,
          user:'myuser',
          password:'mypass',
          database:'example',
          connectionLimit: 10
      });
      return conectando;
  }
```

pero se da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrian decir que estoy haciendo mal, espero me ayuden.
Ya configure el security group para que abra el puerto 3306:
 MYSQL/Aurora TCP 3306 0.0.0.0/0 – EMisaelG 1 min ago   Edit   Delete

Actualizacion**** 
Cambie: host: 'myIpIntance' por host: 'Public DNS (IPv4)' de mi instancia y se salta este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow!, intenta evitar adjuntar fotos, puedes pasar el codigo/errores en formato texto :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error es bastante específico: (traducción propia)

> Error: has intentado llamar .then(), .catch() o has invocado await en el resultado de una consulta que no es una promesa, lo cual es un error de programación.

Dicho esto, el error lo cometes al intentar usar `await` en un método que no devuelve una promesa.

De la documentación de la librería [`mysql2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2), se tiene lo siguiente:

> MySQL2 también provee un método `.promise()` sobre `Pools`, para que puedas crear conexiones basadas o no en Promesas, usando el mismo `Pool`.

Por lo tanto, podrías exportar solamente el objeto `pool` en tu módulo de conexión:

```
import { createPool } from 'mysql2';

const pool = createPool({
  host:'myIPInstance',
  port: 3306,
  user:'myuser',
  password:'mypass',
  database:'example',
  connectionLimit: 10
});

export default pool;
```

Luego, en cualquiera de los módulos donde uses tu conexión `pool` podrás hacerlo usando `await` si se cumplen las siguientes 2 condiciones:

1. Se ejecuta dentro de una función `async`.
2. Creas una instancia del objeto `pool` usando el método `promise()`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
import pool from './connectPool'; // <- nombre del módulo que creamos anteriormente

const main = async () => {
  const promisePool = pool.promise(); // ahora promisePool devuelve promesas, puedo usar await
  try{
    const[rows, fields] = await promisePool.query('SELECT 1');
    console.log(rows);
    console.log(fields);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
  promisePool.end(); // <- cierra todas las conexiones a la DB
}
// llamamos a la función para que se ejecute
main();
```

Esta sería una forma de lograr lo que te propones, existen muchas otras y todas dependerán de lo que intentas implementar. Yo expongo esta solución para explicarte el error que está generando tu código actual.

**Nota**

Recuerda que cada vez aque trabajes con Promesas o con `async/await`, debes usar bloques `try catch`, tal como los uso en mi ejemplo. Esto es algo que se nos olvida muchas veces, pero es importante para depurar errores y evitar que nuestra aplicación sufra un fallo imprevisto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por compartir tu conocimiento, estoy probando esta forma.

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudar. Si te ha sido útil la respuesta la puedes [aceptar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) como válida. Puedes leer [*¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

security group , puede que tu ip sea dinamica por lo tanto deberias si solo estas haciendo pruebas podrias abrir la BD para cualquier IP , si no es el caso creo que intentas hacer un pool de conexiones o semejante , si es un servidor de la capa gratuita de AWS no se si tiene alguna limitación , deberías revisarla pueden tener ciertas limitaciones

Comment: SkyZero, gracias por comentar. La ip no es dinámica, ya tiene su elastic ip.